# AWS Lambda Function Skips Code \ Logs Are Missing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-step-functions

I'm having weird issues a lambda function running on NodeJS.

According to CloudWatch logs, it looks like it skips ~10 lines of codes not showing ~3 printouts to the log.

The first log to be missing is of running a query to MySQL RDS:

```
 var query = con.query(myquery,[orders.SupplierID,orders.sub,orders.DeliveryDate, orders.CustomerComments,orders.TrackingNumber,orders.orderJson],function(err,rows){
console.log(query.sql);
if(err){ 
      console.log("The Query = ",query.sql);
      console.log('ERROR DB' , err);
      throw err;
}
```

Using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

In addition, a variable that I initialize is getting the value of the previous run of this specific lambda function.

```
var executionName = orderIdJson.OrderID.toString() + "_" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').replace(/-/g,'_').replace(' ','_').replace(/:/g,'_');
```

The full code of the lambda function is below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var myrows;

function createConnection() {

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '****',
    port: '3306',
    user: '*****',
    password: '88888*****',
    database: 'db2b2b'
  });
  return con;
}

function startExecution(orderIdJsonStr) {
  var stepfunctions = null;
  stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

  var orderIdJson = JSON.parse(orderIdJsonStr);

  console.log(orderIdJson);

  var executionName = orderIdJson.OrderID.toString() + "_" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').replace(/-/g, '_').replace(' ', '_').replace(/:/g, '_');
  console.log("Order created, starting workflow " + executionName);

  var params = null;

  params = {
    stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:453682599770:stateMachine:Post-Order-WF',
    input: orderIdJsonStr,
    name: executionName
  };

  console.log(params);


  // start a state machine
  stepfunctions.startExecution(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      // *** THIS IS WHERE THE LOG STARTS AGAIN ***
      console.log(err);
      console.log("could not create order", orderIdJson)
      //callback(err, null);
      return;
    }

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'started state machine',
        result: data
      })
    };
  });
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  console.log("EVENT", event);

  var con = createConnection();

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error connecting to Db');
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

  });

  console.log("con", con);

  var orders = {
    SupplierID: event['body-json'].SupplierID,
    sub: event.context.sub,
    DeliveryDate: event['body-json'].DeliveryDate,
    CustomerComments: event['body-json'].CustomerComments,
    TrackingNumber: event['body-json'].TrackingNumber,
    orderJson: event['body-json'].orderJson
  };

  console.log("orders", orders);

  var myquery = 'call usp_createOrder(?,?,?,?,?,?)';

  console.log("myquery", myquery);
  // *** myquery IS WHERE THE LOG STOPS ***

  var query = con.query(myquery, [orders.SupplierID, orders.sub, orders.DeliveryDate, orders.CustomerComments, orders.TrackingNumber, orders.orderJson], function(err, rows) {
    console.log(query.sql);
    if (err) {
      console.log("The Query = ", query.sql);
      console.log('ERROR DB', err);
      throw err;
    }

    myrows = rows;

    console.log(myrows);

    var orderIdJsonStr = JSON.stringify(myrows[0][0]);

    console.log(orderIdJsonStr);

    startExecution(orderIdJsonStr);

    con.end(function(err) {
      const res = myrows;
      console.log(res[0]);
      context.succeed(res[0]);
    });
  });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need to show us more of your code, because there isn't enough context, here.  Most likely, you're making an incorrect assumption about order of execution of asynchronous functions.  Those log entries you are showing would not log anything unless the query fails.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I just did. thank you!

Comment: My assumption was correct.   `var query = con.query(..., function() {...` is asynchronous, so `con.end(function(err) {...` executes *immedately* after the query above it *is started* (not when it is finished).  Async functions do not  block the program flow.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks a lot for your help. Can you advise further:

1. Should I move `con.end()` to inside `con.query(..., function() {` or to the callback of execution the step function, meaning to `stepfunctions.startExecution(params, (err, data) => {`?

2. In mysql npm documentation ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#terminating-connections)), it says `con.end()` is graceful, meaning it should make sure all previously enqueued queries are still before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server. Isn't that contradicts your conclusion?